# How to extract a list of same element type from a soap response?

Tags: java, soap

How do I extract all "BalDtoList" elements from XML below, e,g in a List, from below soap response?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:QueryAcctBal
        xmlns:ns="">
        <BalDtoList>
            <BalID>105529650</BalID>
            <AcctResID>1</AcctResID>
            <BalType>3</BalType>
            <Balance>9363</Balance>
            <EffDate>2014-04-30 15:24:31</EffDate>
        </BalDtoList>
        <BalDtoList>
            <BalID>2100000425</BalID>
            <AcctResID>5025</AcctResID>
            <BalType>1</BalType>
            <Balance>4560</Balance>
            <EffDate>2019-11-29 04:10:36</EffDate>
        </BalDtoList>
        <BalDtoList>
            <BalID>2100000413</BalID>
            <AcctResID>5008</AcctResID>
            <BalType>1</BalType>
            <Balance>60</Balance>
            <EffDate>2019-11-29 04:10:36</EffDate>
        </BalDtoList>
        <BalDtoList>
            <BalID>2100000401</BalID>
            <AcctResID>5011</AcctResID>
            <BalType>9</BalType>
            <Balance>80</Balance>
            <EffDate>2019-11-29 04:10:36</EffDate>
        </BalDtoList>
        <ResultMsg>success</ResultMsg>
    </ns:QueryAcctBal>
</soapenv:Body>
```

Below is my code function, in this I am extracting attributes from SOAP Message.

```
    public static void ExtractingWalletInfo(String message,String mobno) {
    try {

        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(message.getBytes());
        SOAPMessage respMsg = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage(null, is);
        SOAPBody body = respMsg.getSOAPBody();
        NodeList Bal = body.getElementsByTagName("BalDtoList");

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi Rajan, 

speaking about SOAP ws, I think the community can provide a lot better answer if you provide wsdl (file or link).

Comment: sorry @AndreaDeSimone i can't provide wsdl file as it is confidential. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Web services client (SOAP)

If you must access a [SOAP](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12/#intro) web services interface use [JAX-WS](https://javaee.github.io/metro-jax-ws/doc/user-guide/ch04.html#tools-wsimport) (provided with JDK, `jdk/bin/wsimport` ), [Apache Axis](http://axis.apache.org/), [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/how-do-i-develop-a-client.html) or some other framework to generate a web services client.

## Parsing XML

If you don't have access to SOAP interface but you're just trying parse XML documents (like SOAP envelope) use [DocumentBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html), for example like this:

```java
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder =
    DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Reader in = new StringReader(message);
Document document = documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(in));
in.close();
NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagName("BalDtoList");
for(int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    Element elem = (Element) nodes.item(i);
    System.out.println(i + ":");
    for (String name : new String[] {
        "BalID", "AcctResID", "BalType", "Balance", "EffDate"
    }) {
        String value = elem.getElementsByTagName(name).item(0).getTextContent();
        System.out.println(name + " = " + value);
    }
}
```

The output is

```
0:
BalID = 105529650
AcctResID = 1
BalType = 3
Balance = 9363
EffDate = 2014-04-30 15:24:31
1:
BalID = 2100000425
AcctResID = 5025
BalType = 1
Balance = 4560
EffDate = 2019-11-29 04:10:36
...
```

Btw, your XML document is not valid because it's missing the closing tag `</soapenv:Envelope>` for the root element.

Comment: may be while copying here i missed </soapenv:Envelope> .

Comment: Thanks @haba713 , now i am able to fetch each element. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Great! I added a short introduction to WS clients also.